# Select unique values sorted by date

Tags: postgresql, unique, plpgsql

I am trying to solve an interesting problem.  I have a table that has, among other data, these columns (dates in this sample are shown in European format - dd/mm/yyyy):

```
n_place_id   dt_visit_date
(integer)    (date)
==========   =============
   1           10/02/2012
   3           11/03/2012
   4           11/05/2012
  13           14/06/2012
   3           04/10/2012
   3           03/11/2012
   5           05/09/2012
  13           18/08/2012
```

Basically, each place may be visited multiple times - and the dates may be in the past (completed visits) or in the future (planned visits).  For the sake of simplicity, today's visits are part of planned future visits.

Now, I need to run a select on this table, which would pull **unique** place IDs from this table (without date) sorted in the following order:

1. Future visits go before past visits
2. Future visits take precedence in sorting over past visits for the same place
3. For future visits, the earliest date must take precedence in sorting for the same place
4. For past visits, the latest date must take precedence in sorting for the same place.

For example, for the sample data shown above, the result I need is:

```
 5     (earliest future visit)
 3     (next future visit into the future)
13     (latest past visit)
 4     (previous past visit)
 1     (earlier visit in the past)
```

Now, I can achieve the desired sorting using `case when` in the `order by` clause like so:

```
select
    n_place_id
from
    place_visit
order by
    (case when dt_visit_date >= now()::date then 1 else 2 end),
    (case when dt_visit_date >= now():: date then 1 else -1 end) * extract(epoch from dt_visit_date)
```

This *sort of* does what I need, but it does contain repeated IDs, whereas I need unique place IDs.   If I try to add `distinct` to the select statement, postgres complains that I must have the `order by` in the select clause - but then the unique won't be sensible any more, as I have dates in there.

Somehow I feel that there should be a way to get the result I need in one select statement, but I can't get my head around how to do it.

If this can't be done, then, of course, I'll have to do the whole thing in the code, but I'd prefer to have this in one SQL statement.

P.S. I am not worried about the performance, because the dataset I will be sorting is not large.  After the `where` clause will be applied, it will rarely contain more than about 10 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 select n_place_id
 from 
 (
    select *, 
    extract(epoch from (dt_visit_date - now())) as seconds,  
    1 - SIGN(extract(epoch from (dt_visit_date - now())) ) as futurepast
    from #t
 ) v
 group by n_place_id
 order by max(futurepast) desc, min(abs(seconds))
```

Comment: I get error `cannot cast interval to integer` in line `cast((dt_visit_date - now()) as int) as days`

Comment: Yep! This is about it.  Just had to change `SIGN(...)` to `1 - SIGN(...)` - and it did the trick.  Many thanks!

Comment: @AleksG: That's odd. I get correct results with podiluska's *original* query, not with your amended version.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That **is** odd.  I had to put `1-` in to get the results I needed.

Comment: @AleksG: With correct results I mean the result displayed in my answer for the example in your question. podiluska edited his answer, maybe you built on his original version, but mistakenly edited his final version?

Answer (score 2):

With [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) you can easily show additional columns of the row with the resulting `n_place_id`:

```
SELECT n_place_id, dt_visit_date
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (n_place_id) *
         ,dt_visit_date < now()::date    AS prio  -- future first
         ,@(now()::date - dt_visit_date) AS diff  -- closest first
   FROM   place_visit
   ORDER  BY n_place_id, prio, diff
   ) x
ORDER  BY prio, diff;
```

Effectively I pick the row with the earliest future date (including "today") per `n_place_id` - or latest date in the past, failing that.
Then the resulting unique rows are sorted by the same criteria.

- `FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`
- The ["absolute value" `@`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html) helps to sort "closest first"
- More on the Postgres specific [`DISTINCT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860) in this related answer.

Result:

```
 n_place_id | dt_visit_date
------------+--------------
 5          | 2012-09-05
 3          | 2012-10-04
 13         | 2012-08-18
 4          | 2012-05-11
 1          | 2012-02-10
```